# Send table row created by java server page to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I  create tabla by jsp.This table read data from Person tabla(Database)and put in html table
 In each row has two button one for delete and another for edit
I want by clicking on edit button get the value of cells in Confirm form in the             same page.
Information is created by jsp send for confirm form

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/table.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="updialog">
    <form>
        <label>ID:</label> <br><br>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname"><br><br>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="INS" value="Confirm"><br><br>
    </form>
</div>

<%!
    ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
    PersonTable pt = new PersonTable();//read data form database
%>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First_Name</th>
        <th>Last_Name</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        person = pt.readPersonTable();
        for (Person p : person) {
    %>

    <tr>
        <td id="<%= p.getId()%>_ID">
            <%= p.getId()%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= p.getfName()%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= p.getlName()%>
        </td>
        <td style="background-color:white">
            <input type="button" id="<%= p.getId()%>_edit" class="edit" name="Edit">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="Delete" id="<%= p.getId()%>_del" class="del">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have all those values in `person` array so you just need to find that id from array and based on that you can get details. And also you have to use form instead of just buttons.
You can try below approach :

```
<%!
    ArrayList<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
    PersonTable pt = new PersonTable();//read data form database
    person = pt.readPersonTable();
%>

<%
    String id = request.getAttribute("editId");
    if( id != null)
    {
        for (Person p : person) {
            if(id.equals(p.getId())) {          
%>
<form>
    <label>ID: <%= p.getId()%> </label> <br><br>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" value="<%= p.getfName()%>"><br><br>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="<%= p.getlName()%>"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="INS" value="Confirm"><br><br>
</form>
<%
            }
        }
    }
%>

<table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First_Name</th>
    <th>Last_Name</th>
</tr>
<%
    for (Person p : person) {
%>

<tr>
    <form action="#?editId=<%= p.getId()%>" method="GET">
    <td id="<%= p.getId()%>_ID">
        <%= p.getId()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= p.getfName()%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= p.getlName()%>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:white">
        <input type="submit" id="<%= p.getId()%>_edit" class="edit" name="Edit">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="Delete" id="<%= p.getId()%>_del" class="del">
    </td>
    </form>
</tr>
<%
    }
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it use java .I want send data to form using javascript